# Java Gui Thread Coding?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, netbeans, tcp

I got problem when my server connected to the client this exception is occur then my program not respond after connected. I use netbeans gui designer to generated code for gui class. I also comment the line number which show in exception below in my code for you guys considering. Everything work find before socket accept. Please help!

> Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   serverui.ServerUi.StartServer(ServerUi.java:62)       at
>   serverui.ServerThread.run(ServerUi.java:19)       at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

```
class ServerThread implements Runnable{

public void run(){
 try {
      ServerUi t = new ServerUi();
      t.StartServer(); //Line 19
     } catch (IOException ex) {
       //Logger.getLogger(ServerThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            //Logger.getLogger(ServerThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}


public class ServerUi {
byte s = 0;
static ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
Socket clientSocket = null;
PrintWriter out = null;
BufferedReader in = null;
public static boolean checklisten = false;
static gui winframe = null;
public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {

winframe = new gui();
serverSocket = new ServerSocket(10007);
Thread tserver = new Thread(new ServerThread());
tserver.start();

java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                winframe.setVisible(true);
            }
        });


    }

    public void StartServer()throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {

               winframe.displayMessage("Listening for Connection");
               clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
               winframe.displayMessage("Connected");
               String inputLine;
               while(true){
                while((inputLine=in.readLine()) != null) // Line 62
                {

                    winframe.displayMessage("Server: "+ inputLine);
                    out.println(inputLine);

                    if(inputLine.equals("Bye."))
                    {
                        this.Closeconnection();
                        break;
                    }

                    if(winframe.checkdisconnectbtn == true)
                    {
                        this.Closeconnection();
                        break;
                    }

                }

               }
    }
```

Comment: Removed "[Solved: Just missing In and Out initialize]" from title by rolling back the edit. Instead you should accept the answer that helped you, or post your own solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never initialize your `BufferedReader`.

```
BufferedReader in = null;
```

... therefore this line fails with a `NullPointerException`:

```
while((inputLine=in.readLine()) != null) // Line 62
```

In general, whenever you see a `NullPointerException`, all you have to do is look at the line and check all the objects which are invoking methods for `null`.

Comment: Thank you,sir! I miss that.

Comment: @SarinSuriyakoon Any time!  Glad it helped you. :)  In general, whenever you see `NullPointerException`, just look at the line and check all the variables which are invoking methods for `null`.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't initialize in.

```
in = new BufferedReader(arguments);
```